# Ionic 7 Angular 15: ion-datetime picker doesn't paint intermittently if used in multiple components

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic7

I have several forms that use multiple ion-datetime pickers as components.  For example, on a single form - a component for event start date and time, and another one for event end date and time.  Each component uses ion-datetime and they are activated via modals.  When both paint, I can select the dates and times I desire.  However, intermittently after I select the start date and time, the end date and time component doesn't paint.   It shows month, year and time but no dates to pick from.  Is there any code I need to insert in the second component to avoid this?

```
/** from myview.page.ts **/
async openStartDayModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: DateTimeComponent,
    });
    modal.present();

    const { data, role } = await modal.onWillDismiss();

    if (role === 'confirm') {
      this.postData.startdate = `${data}`;
        }
  }

 async openEndDayModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: DateTimeEndComponent,
    });
    modal.present();

    const { data, role } = await modal.onWillDismiss();

    if (role === 'confirm') {
      this.postData.enddate = `${data}`;
        }
  }
```

```
/*** from my enddate.component.ts file.  Start Date component is exactly the same as the End Date component except that variable for value is startdate. ***/

 dateChanged(value) {
        this.enddate = value;

 }

confirm() {
       return this.modalCtrl.dismiss(this.enddate, 'confirm');
}

/*** Its HTML ***/

<ion-datetime #datetime [value]="enddate" (ionChange)="dateChanged(datetime.value)" ></ion-datetime>
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you add a snippet of your code to have a better understanding of your issue

Comment: The issue is not related to the code itself because code works fine.  The issue is if two fields that use the same ionic component are next to each other, one has performance issues and occasionally  doesn't paint.

Comment: are you using the `ion-datetime-button`? Remember that each ionic datetime should have a unique `id` so you can handle separately, maybe this is your case?

Comment: No.  <ion-datetime presentation="date"></ion-datetime>

Comment: so you have 2 components for handling dates? one for endDate and the other for startDate? why not create a single, generic datetime component? AFAIK, endDate and startDate components have the same logic so you are pretty much repeating yourself. The code posted doesn't tell much of where the issue might be, maybe you could create a simple repo ionic-angular project with this scenario and share it here. I have the feeling that since you have 2 components that share the same `#datetime`, one could be overriding the other one or something similar...

Comment: @Andres2142 - I have two components because both have to show selected dates in the form. Yes, I know that its the same code.  Like I said before, the issue is not with the code.  It seems like I need to do something else so that the second date window paints during the selection.